# how to use content_for so that the content shows up in the layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, content-for

Am testing the content_for in my rails 3.2 app and following the rails guides but they are specific to the actual files and I cannot seem to get the yield to work:

application.html.erb file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
 ...
</head>

<body>




<%= yield :navigation %> #shouldn't this load the content_for block named :navigation specified in the _main_nav.html.erb partial? 

 <%= yield %>  #this load the index page content


</body>
 </html>
```

I created a layout file _main_nav.html.erb (i know I can render with <%= render 'layouts/header' %> but I am trying to use the content_for instead)   The _main_nav.html.erb is:

```
<% content_for :navigation do %>
<ul>
 <li>Home</li>
 </ul>

<% end %>
```

They way I read the RailsGuide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method
this should work.  But it does not.   I do not get an error.   Seems simple but I am stumped.

When I go to my index.html.erb file I would expect to see this result:

- Home

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I think I have a solution for this. Your code:

```
<% content_for :navigation do %>
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

should be at the top of the file that is *loading*. Your _header.html.erb is a partial. If you move this code into views/tasks/new.html.erb then it works as expected.

However, for it to work as you want, then you need to adjust your application.html.erb file:

```
<p>this is where we should see the "Home" link appear that is defined in _header.html.erb:</p>
<section class="header">
<% render 'layouts/header' %>
<%= yield :navigation %>
</section>
```

Notice, that I have called the render erb tag without the = sign. This means I don't see the contents of the header partial, but it does load. If you include the = sign then it still works but also renders any other content you may have in the partial.
Note: The render tag has to be above/before the yield tag.

Comment: no worries @akkdio, I also did a pull request to your GitHub repo. Any questions just ask. I'm a newbie, but I think I understand what is going on with this one!

Answer (score 15):

I believe what you want to have is have a view that will contain your `content_for` block. So an example would be if you have the following:

**index.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :head do %> 
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'users' %> 
  #Above this will load the users stylesheet
<% end %> 

<h2>Example</h2> 
  <ul>
    <% @users.each do |users| %> 
      <li><%= user.name %></li>
    <% end %> 
  </ul>
```

Then to output what inside the `users` stylesheet we can yield and pass in the symbol of the name of the `content_for`.

**Application.html.erb**

```
    <!-DOCTYPE html> 
      <html> 
        <head> 
         <%= yield :head%>
           <title>This is my title</title 
         </head> 
        <body>
        <p>This is a test</p> 
        <%= yield %> 
     </html>
```

So to review whats happening here is that, in my example I am saying I have a `users` stylesheet that I would like to load into the `<head></head>` of my application.html.erb. To do this I set the `content_for` which is a Rails helper and give it the identifier sysmbol which is `head` which is then called in the `application.html.erb` where I do `yeild :head`. So what I am getting my application to do is when the my `index.html.erb` for that page is being rendered the `application.html.erb` will load my `users` stylesheet. Hope this clears things up for you.

**Update explanation**

To add to this another thing the purpose of combination of using `content_for` with `yield` is to allow you to inject data into the application layout from **ANY** view. So as another example. You could have the following:

```
<% content_for :title do %> My Title<% end %>
```

Here when the controller renders the view template and combines it with the application layout, the text `My title` will be replaced. The `yield(:head)` makes it easy to add more elements to the specific page if needed. Take a look at the following example:

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<% if content_for?(:navbar) %>
  <%= yield(:navbar) %>
<% else %>
  <%# default navbar %>
  <section class="navbar"></section>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/blah/index.html.erb**

```
<% content_for(:navbar) do %>
  <section class="navbar"></section>
<% end %>
```

And a further note not sure how your developing your application or what design framework your using but you could also take a look at [Rails-Bootstrap-Navbar](https://github.com/julescopeland/Rails-Bootstrap-Navbar). May also be an alternative.

Comment: David,   Thank you.  You are correct in that my example was not like the guide -I have updated it to be more specific about what I am trying to do... It seems that the content_for block should be abled to be called anywhere in the views by just putting <%= yield :header %> however I cannot even get this simple example to work.   I must not be understanding it or have to do something else to get things to appear...

Comment: David, I really appreciate you taking the time to understand my question and am sorry it was a little confusing... I see what you have  done and understand it as it relates to the stylesheet.  Where I am unclear is why when I try to create a nav to use the content_for nothing shows up?   Please if you can look at my reworked example and let me know if you spot anything  wrong in my thinking.

Comment: @akkdio take another look at the further updated example with an additional link

Comment: David,  Thank you again.  I tried your example in my app and it did not work.  It is something simple I am sure.  But what? To help I put my example on Github ( https://github.com/akkdio/content_for ) with the hope that a quick look will spot my error and thinking.  The bootstrap link is interesting... however, I am attempting to understand bits and pieces first.   Thank you again.

Comment: @akkdio can you actually explain to me why you are actually rendering two `yield` blocks in the `body` tag. I don't know if it just me but I think you separate this out in to some sort of `div`. So maybe for your header you could have `<div class="container_header"></div> and encase your `yeild` inside this. If this does not work you could just simply try and do `<%= render 'layouts/header'` and have done with and have this render your content for you.

Comment: David, The example is contrived to focus on the content_for and try to get it to work.   I pushed an update to git to make it more "realistic" adding section divs.  The point was to learn about the content_for method to be able use it.   I will continue to try to understand why my example is wrong.  However, I thank you for your help and time you took to get me a little further down the path...

Comment: Helped me to understand how this _helper_ method really work.. Thanks!!