# How to conditionally add class to <body> in rails layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My **application.html.erb** file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  .
  .
  .
  </head>
  <body <%= "class=landing-bg" if !@landing.nil? %>>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
    .
    .
    .
    </div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    <% if !@landing.nil? %>
      <div class="landing-gradient"></div>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've left out a bunch of meta tags in the `<head>` and a bunch of other code in the body that's unrelated to the question.

**static_pages_controller**

```
def home
  @landing = "landing"
end
```

I need to add a class to `<body>` and a div below the footer only on my home page. I feel like what I am doing is a bit hacky.  And, if I created a separate layout just for the landing page it wouldn't be DRY since I would be repeating alot of code that's on this layout.

What is the best way to do this? What is the rails way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My typical pattern is to add the controller and action into the class of the body, and then use those as selectors in my css like this:

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
  <!-- etc -->
</body>
```

---

As for your second issue of a conditionally body on only the home page, you can simply add that into the body in the main layout and display it only on the landing page:

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
  <!-- etc -->
  <div class="landing-gradient"></div>
</body>

# application.css
.landing-gradient {
  display: none;               // Hide the gradient
}

.landing .landing-gradient {
   display: inline;            // Show gradient b/c of more specific selector
}
```

This is my personal preference since you're leaving display of individual elements to the css / presentation layer instead of within your controllers.

Finally, you could also use a [`content_for` around the footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757176/how-to-use-content-for-so-that-the-content-shows-up-in-the-layout) so that you can customize the footer across individual pages. That's a bit heavy handed for your example though, so I'd only use that if you were customizing the footer a lot.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I want to have a different class per layout (at least potentially), so in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` I do this:

```
<body class="<%= yield(:body_class) %>">
```

and then in my layout file I do this:

```
<% content_for(:body_class) { 'my-class' } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also manage it without creating an instance variable and verifying it in your view but using the `params[:action]` and `params[:controller]`:

```
<body class="<% 'class_value' if params[:controller] == 'static_pages' && params[:action] == 'home' %>"
```

You can just validate for the action (method) if you don't have more than one `home` method.